# Adobe Air Application - Not in background and not in Foreground - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air

I have an adobe air application - AS3 for iOs and Android.

Whenever the user clicks the home button, and thus the application is now in the background, the application automatically stops, which is the expected behavior.
 Now, if the user is in the application, and he double clicks his home button, showing all the multiple windows, the application continues running, which is not what i want.
 How can i access that state ( Not Background, not foreground )? If i can access it, i would then put my pausing code into that state, but how can i access that particular state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks the home button the app is moved to the background and suspended. The app isn't closed. The OS can close the app to free memory. If your app is a memory hog you'll see this happening.

You use events dispatched by the NativeApplication object. Below is example code to listen and handle these events.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;

// create listeners to NativeApplication
private var naApplication: NativeApplication;
naApplication = NativeApplication.nativeApplication;

naApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, eActivate);
naApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, eDeactivate);
naApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, eExiting);

private function eActivate(e: Event): void {
    // app has opened or resumed 
    application.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
}

private function eDeactivate(e: Event): void {
    // app is going to be moved to background 
    application.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
}

private function eExiting(e: Event): void {
    // app is going to be closed by user or by the OS (usually to free up memory)
    // do whatever exit code here then remove all listeners (to be clean don't rely on OS to close them) 
    application.removeEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, eActivate);
    application.removeEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, eDeactivate);
    application.removeEventListener(Event.EXITING, eExiting);
    application.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL;
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eMainTimer);
}
```

The systemIdleMode and ENTER_FRAME are just examples of typical code. Let me know of any questions.

Comment: thank you so much for replying, i will try it asap , and get back to you !